# Trying to install gems ERROR

Tags: command-line, software-installation, permissions

I was trying to install the gems for RoR and this error appears :

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.4
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/lib/gems
```

What can I do to properly install gems?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need super-user rights to modify anything in the `/` directory.

So you'd need to run the installation as super-user:

```
sudo gem install rails -v 4.2.4
```

Answer (score 3):

As normal user you have no rights to create the necessary folder in `/var/lib`. Therefore start the installation via

```
sudo gem install rails -v 4.2.4
```

Or for Ruby >= 1.9

```
sudo gem install rails:4.2.4
```